# Assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, variable-assignment, uint8t

I really don't understand why I have such error knowing that `tmp` and `key` are the same type and size.

```
uint8_t key[8] = {0x00,0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06,0x07};

void change() {

    int i;
    uint8_t *tmp[8];

    for(i=0; i<8; i++){
        tmp[i] = key[(i+3)%8];
    }
}
```

This produces:

> warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion

Answer (score 2):

> *`tmp` and `key` are the same type*

**NO**. They are not. They both are arrays, but the datatype is different. One is a `uint8_t *`array, another is a `uint8_t` array.

Change

```
 uint8_t *tmp[8];
```

to

```
uint8_t tmp[8] = {0};
```

Comment: It wasn't my downvote, but I don't see where his code uses a pointer from `tmp` uninitialized. He's *assigning* to the `i`th item of `tmp`, not dereferencing it. It's hardly undefined behavior to assign to an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: @CodyGray You're right sir, I also got confused by the data types....Thanks for pointing that out. But then, regarding the DV, it was before I added that part, as an edit.....so, .... :(

Answer (score 1):

Not clear what you want here but if you want `tmp[x]` to reflect the value in `key[y]` then

```
tmp[i] = &key[(i+3)%8]; /* tmp[i] now points at key[ (i+3)%8];
// key[3] = 5;    /* These two lines modify the same memory */
// (*tmp[0]) = 5; /*                                        */
```

Otherwise if you want tmp to be separate, then ...

```
 uint8_t tmp[8];  /* change type to be non-pointer. */
```